# Emacs freeze after selecting a org-capture template

Tags: org-mode, org-capture

I'm new to org-mode. I've tried to set up a simple TODO list by calling org-capture and when I select my [t] todo item on *Org Select*, Emacs freezes and I need to kill its process.

On the mini-buffer I can read the following error message:

> Clipboard pasted as level 2 subtree
>
> Error in post-command-hook (linum-update-current): (args-out-of-range 1 1)

I've updated all packages to the latest version, and reinstalled the latest Emacs 25, but the error persisted. Does anyone have an idea where this might be coming from? Am I overseeing something very simple?

Thanks a lot.

In case this is important..

on init.el:

```
(setq org-capture-templates
       '(("t" "todo" entry (file+headline "/Users/dgomez/todo.org" "Tasks")
          "* TODO [#A] %?")))
```

GNU Emacs 25.0.50.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0, NS appkit-1404.13 Version 10.11.1 (Build 15B42)) of 2015-11-25

Comment: A "freeze" could mean different things. Consider reporting a bug, providing a step-by-step recipe that starts with `emacs -Q` (no init file): `M-x report-emacs-bug`. Note too that you are using a development snapshot, and those are generally unstable - anything goes.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I found out that the problem is a conflict between linum-mode and org-capture. My question is, should I report this? And who do I report it to?

Comment: `M-x report-emacs-bug`. That will gather info about your session (which you can edit, if you want). `C-c` will prepare the report to be emailed. Try to provide a minimal step-by-step recipe, from `emacs -Q`.

Answer (score 2):

I had `(global-linum-mode 1)` on my init.el, and that conflicts with org-capture somehow.
I've changed it to `(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'linum-mode)` and the issue was gone.

Apparently linum-mode is not compatible with org-capture.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, I ran into the same problem. `org` and `linum` are somehow incompatible.
As a different solution you can also use a hook and simply disable `linum-mode` when `org` is the major mode.
I also do this for `drag-stuff` since it violates `org-mode`'s shortcuts.

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 
          (lambda () 
            (drag-stuff-mode -1) 
            (linum-mode -1)))
```